# Are all students considered expats?

Tags: discussion

What kind of criteria will we use to determine if an abroad student-related question belongs to Expats.SE or Travel.SE?

Answer (score 8):

If you go abroad for holiday student exchange (2-4 weeks) it could be considered travel, but in all other cases, especially staying abroad one full semester or longer, the differences are immence. Just to mention a few:

- as traveller you stay in hotel/hostel/shelter/tent/whatever, as a student you need more permanent place to live, such as renting an appartment, registering to dormitory
- some countries require registration from travellers even for short term, but in case of studying, just like when working, usually domicile arises.
- if VISA are needed, those are not travel VISAs, but long-term VISAs
- as a traveller you don't usually have to buy clothing, go to hairdresser etc., all such things you do before and after travel
- you need to take a lot more of things with you when going on studies, additional issues arises
- money: taking all money with you is no more viable, you need to establish money transfer procedure, open bank account etc.

Answer (score 7):

I think if you are spending at least one semester in a foreign country you are no longer travelling but essentially living there, so I'd allow these kinds of questions. This for example includes questions related to living abroad as an Erasmus student.

What I would deem off-topic:

- Questions that completely apply to local students as well (in which case this might belong to Academia.SE or similar).
- Questions that only apply for short term stay (like 1 month only)